# Angular 2 app loads too slow and bundle file size is huge

Tags: angular

I am building an angular 2 app and its working fine ng build or AOT build, only issue I am facing right now is its loading time and file size.
It takes around 2 minutes to load on localhost and system/browser hangs for a while.

Ultimately this project is going to be live on server and as a beginner I am not sure that I need to upload the build or I need to upload the files only and they will be compiled on server directly ?

I searched a lot a found tutorials to develop app on localhost system only.

After starting on app I have following queries, I wonder if someone can help me out.

1.Id build the only method to make the app live or is there any run time compilation method where I need to upload the files only and app will run on domain after compilation ?

2.What are the best practices to build a huge app, my project is going to be huge and will load data with cloud based rest API's so I am not sure how should I proceed with it.

3.How to reduce app size and file size , right now when I build it generates 4MB vendor file along with other files in KB's ?

I know question scope is huge but I didnt fine any other forum to ask this, its hard to figure out the exact approach for a online learner like me, there are lot of tutorial, examples etc and hard to decide which one should I follow.

Any help will be appreciable.

Thanks

Comment: what do you use for the build? ng-cli? webpack? what is your module loader? sytemjs?

Comment: I tried with ng-cli but it takes too long to build and file size is huge , now trying to use webpack

Comment: ng-cli uses webpack under the hood

Answer (score 1):

> use ng build --aot --prod

- --aot does angular compliation of js files which i think you are doing,
- --prod will minify the bundles generated from compilation,this you might be missing.This might reduce your vendor bundle size