# Why angular packages are separated and why we need them

Tags: angular, npm, package

I have started building a new angular 2 app. I have gone through the articles and downloaded some free apps from github, all of them have angular/comman package along with some other packages. I installed angular package and it added `"angular": "^1.6.5"` in package.json file. I am not sure if we can have full package then why we install comman package separately ?

When I checked other app then they mostly have following

```
"@angular/common": "2.0.1",
"@angular/compiler": "2.0.1",
"@angular/core": "2.0.1",
"@angular/forms": "2.0.1",
"@angular/http": "2.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.1",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.1",
"@angular/router": "3.0.1",
```

are they all part of angular core ? I can not see angular package here.

Is there any article or guidelines for angular 2 packages ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is the brief description of each package:

#### Required

- @angular/core - contains core functionality like decorators, component views, change detection etc.
- @angular/compiler - contains Angular compiler.

#### Required depending on the environment and setup

- @angular/platform-browser - contains browser specific code required to bootstrap the application and work with the DOM. May not be required if you use Angular on the platform other than browser.
- @angular/platform-browser-dynamic - contains implementations for the dynamic bootstrap of the application. Not required if you use `AOT`.

#### Usually required

- @angular/common - contains common directives and pipes
- @angular/forms - contains forms implementation
- @angular/http - contains http client implementation
- @angular/router - contains router implementation

The reason for not packaging it all into one huge `@angular` package is because you may not need everything in your runtime. You application may not use forms, or built-in directives like `ngFor`, or may not use routing. Why load it all into the browser?

Also, the second group of packages is sometimes required and sometimes not depending on the setup. The only thing that is always required in runtime is `@angular/core`.

See also [the official docs](https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages#feature-packages).

Comment: Also the doc link: https://angular.io/guide/npm-packages#feature-packages

Comment: @echonax, thanks, I'll add the link. Didn't know it existed)

Comment: @Maximus Thanks Dude, that's great info for a beginner, I was struggling to decide the packages for long time.

Comment: @Maximus Thanks ! I wonder if you can share your thoughts on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45185310/angular-2-app-loads-too-slow-and-bundle-file-size-is-huge  and what should I use for my live project angular CLI or webpack ?